# Apache Solr - ID field and field prefixes

Tags: solr

I have the following questions about Apache Solr:

a) The ID field needs to be unique. Are there any format constrains? So far I have just used the IDs from the MySQL database I want to make searchable with Solr.

b) I've read about field prefixes, such as i_fieldname for an integer value. Do field prefixes give me any speed gain? Are they advisible to use? c) If the ID is an integer, should I prefix the ID field too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique field only needs to be, well, unique. It can be a String, an int, a float (although I wouldn't suggest that, as floating point numbers are rather inexact) or any other distinct value. Using the ID from the database is a good solution, as it allows you to match the row from the database to the document in Solr easily.

Field prefixes isn't really prefixes in that sense, they're just dynamic fields - meaning you don't define the field structure in your schema before indexing, you just assume that everything indexed with a field name starting with i_ is an integer. If you know which fields you're going to index, I'd go with defining the fields and the behaviour you want for each field. You can also do both, have some sort of wild card field that catches undefined fields, although you'd probably be better off defining these for the particular use cases you're trying to solve.

I'd not use a dynamic field for the unique field, although you could do this if you wanted to. I do however prefer that the fields are defined in the schema, so that you can do analysis and set store/indexed by a per-field basis. The schema also tells other developers / solr administrators a lot more about the actual structure of your Solr core and how you're using Solr.

Comment: "[...] I'd go with defining the fields and the behaviour you want for each field. [...]" I'm new to Solr.. So far I've managed to feed the relevant data into Solr, where do I define the behaviour for an individual field? (For instance, disallow wildcard search.. is this what you mean by behaviour?)

Comment: By behaviour I mean filters, analyzers, tokenizers, etc. If you look in the example/ directory of a fresh .tar.gz, you'll see that it defines different field types (text_no, text_de, text_en, etc.) that have different chains of processing. You can also change indexed/stored/static boosts for each defined field).

Comment: Are you referring, with "unique field", to the field designated with "<UniqueKey>" in schema.xml?